# MYSQL - Update temp table with next date

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns EquipmentNo (VARCHAR), ActionType (VARCHAR) and ActionDate (DateTime)

When a user checks out some equipment a row would be added like this:

```
EquipmentNo: 123
ActionType: 'checkout'
ActionDate: '2017-02-03 09:05:27'
```

And when they check that equipment back in:

```
EquipmentNo: 123
ActionType: 'checkin'
ActionDate: '2017-02-03 10:32:46'
```

A single piece of equipment can be checked out/checked in multiple times a day, so lets say EquipmentNo 123 had another checkout/check in later on the same day.

```
EquipmentNo: 123
ActionType: 'checkout'
ActionDate: '2017-02-03 11:15:27'

EquipmentNo: 123
ActionType: 'checkout'
ActionDate: '2017-02-03 11:30:55'
```

I need to write a query which calculates the duration of all sessions (difference between checkout and corresponding check in time). the query needs to also sum up how many sessions that equipment has had, in our case it had 2 sessions with a duration of 102 minutes.

Here is what I have so far

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp1 AS (
SELECT EquipmentNo, MIN( ActionDate ) AS CheckOutDate, 
NULL AS CheckInDate, COUNT( * ) AS Sessions
FROM EquipmentSessions WHERE ActionType =  'checkout' GROUP BY EquipmentNo, ActionDate);
```

This yields something like

```
123 | 2017-02-03 09:05:27 | NULL | 1
123 | 2017-02-03 11:15:27 } NULL | 1
```

What I cannot seem to do is workout how to structure my update statement to use this table as the source and basically say "get the next check in date after sourceTable.CheckOutDate for each EquipmentNo".

Comment: Can I assume checkout and checkin will be always alterned?

Comment: Yes - checkout will always be before check in date, no overlaps

Comment: Is it possible that an equipment is checked out at, say, `23:55:00` and checked in back, next day, at `02:00:00`? Which day will the session be attributed to?

Comment: Let's say same day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the table contents look like follows:

```
CREATE TABLE eqp (eno int, action_type varchar(20), action_date timestamp);

INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(124, 'checkout', '2017-02-03 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkout', '2017-02-03 09:05:27');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(124, 'checkin',  '2017-02-03 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkin',  '2017-02-03 10:32:46');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkout', '2017-02-03 11:15:27');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkin',  '2017-02-03 11:30:55');

INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkout', '2017-02-04 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkin',  '2017-02-04 10:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkout', '2017-02-04 15:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkin',  '2017-02-04 17:00:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkout', '2017-02-04 18:30:00');
INSERT INTO eqp VALUES(123, 'checkin',  '2017-02-04 19:00:00');
```

So, assuming the following:

- `checkout` will always precede `checkin` for an equipment
- Both the actions will be completed within the same day, AND
- (An implied assumption) Every equipment that is checked out will have a check in record in the table (before this desired operation is performed)

We can write a single query to fetch all `checkout` events sorted first by equipment and then by time, in the order that they occurred, and assign a `rank` to every record fetched:

```
SELECT @checkoutrank := @checkoutrank + 1 AS rank, eno, action_type, action_date
    FROM eqp, (SELECT @checkoutrank := 0) r
WHERE action_type='checkout'
ORDER BY eno ASC, action_date ASC
```

This gives:

```
 rank   |   eno     | action_type   |   action_date
----------------------------------------------------------
1       |   123     |  checkout     | 2017-02-03 09:05:27
2       |   123     |  checkout     | 2017-02-03 11:15:27   
3       |   123     |  checkout     | 2017-02-04 09:00:00
4       |   123     |  checkout     | 2017-02-04 15:00:00   
5       |   123     |  checkout     | 2017-02-04 18:30:00
6       |   124     |  checkout     | 2017-02-03 09:00:00
```

A similar query can then be written for `checkin` too.

We shall then have two tables — with corresponding `checkout` and `checkin` in the comparable order — and in the sequence that they occurred, thereby giving us start and end time for each individual session for the equipments. These two corresponding tables could now simply be joined over `rank` and `eno` (equipment number) where we can compute the count of `sessions` as well as `SUM` up the time difference between each `checkout` and `checkin`:

```
SELECT checkin.eno, DATE(checkin.action_date) AS session_date, 
    COUNT(*) AS sessions, 
    SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, checkout.action_date, checkin.action_date)) 
             AS sesssion_duration
FROM
    (
        SELECT @checkoutrank := @checkoutrank + 1 AS rank, eno, action_type, action_date
            FROM eqp, (SELECT @checkoutrank := 0) r
        WHERE action_type='checkout'
        ORDER BY eno ASC, action_date ASC
    ) checkout

INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT @checkinrank := @checkinrank + 1 AS rank, eno, action_type, action_date
            FROM eqp, (SELECT @checkinrank := 0) r
        WHERE action_type='checkin'
        ORDER BY eno ASC, action_date ASC
    ) checkin

    ON checkout.rank = checkin.rank
    AND checkout.eno = checkin.eno

GROUP BY checkin.eno, DATE(checkin.action_date)
```

Giving us the output as:

```
eno     | session_date  |   sessions    |   session_duration
--------------------------------------------------------------
123     |   2017-02-03  |       2       |   6167
123     |   2017-02-04  |       3       |   12600
124     |   2017-02-03  |       1       |   3600
```

The `session_duration` above is computed in `SECOND`s for the sake of simplicity as well as accuracy.

[Demo link](http://rextester.com/BIP4428).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I needed

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @andrewb! Do you think it'll be good to update the title of the question to indicate that it's got something to do with consecutive events / timestamp / rows? Cheers!